# Finding the minimum of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, maxima-minima

Let a and b be positve real numbers:
\begin{align}
f(a,b) = \dfrac{4a+b}{2a} + \dfrac{4a-3b}{b}
\end{align}

Where is this function at a minimum?
What is this functions minimum value?

Answer: at a minimum at x = $2\sqrt2$, Minimum value: y = $2\sqrt2 -1$

I managed to take the derivative with respect to a, by first multiplying the denominators to get a common denominator. That gave me $$(4ab+b^2+8a^2-6ba)/2ab$$ After simplifying, I got $$(-2ab+b^2+8a^2)/2ab$$ I then took the derivative and got it all the way down to $$b' = (-16a+2b)/(2a+2b)$$ After simplifying a little bit more and setting the numerator to 0, I tried to get the critical points when I got $$b =8a$$. I realize that if I take the integral here, I will get the answer $$b = 2\sqrt2$$, but what I want to ask is, why would I take the integral there?

Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the question?

All help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum.

Comment: What else should I have provided? this is literally all I was given in the question.
I wrote the question word for word, provided my work, and provided what I cannot figure out. What else do you want me to add?

Comment: You should include your calculations so we can point where you could had made a mistake.

Comment: By the way, saying that the minimum is achieved at $2\sqrt{2}$ makes no sense. Since it's a two variable function, the minimum is achieved at a **pair** of values $(a,b)$

Comment: I wrote it exactly how I was told. I wrote the question just like it's written on the test and I wrote the answer just how it is written on the answer sheet. I think it means that $2\sqrt2$ is the x value, and $2\sqrt2 -1$ is the y

I will show my work some more though, thank you

Comment: Been on the answer sheet don't make it right. Still makes no sense. You should try to understand the problem and the theory to solve it, not to try to figure a way to get to a (in this case, wrong) given answer

Comment: What makes you say that it is wrong? This isn't necessarially a "given" answer, it is the answer. As in, the person that made the test did this, and it is a test that was given out to thousands of people across the world. Something like that cannot be "wrong"

Comment: Ok, you're the expert. I thought you was asking for help

Comment: I am asking for help. If you can tell me what the real reason is with a reason behind it I would gladly listen, but instead all you have told is what I did wrong and how badly structured the question is. I tried understand the question on my own and I couldn't that's why I came here.

Comment: Ok, but then don't use arguments as " it is a test that was given out to thousands of people across the world. Something like that cannot be "wrong" ". The truth of a math statement doesn't care about it been used in a broadly applied exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hint

\begin{align}
\frac{4a + b}{2a} + \frac{4a - 3b}{b} &= 2 + \frac{b}{2a} + \frac{4a}{b} - 3, \; a, b \ne 0 \\
& = \frac{b}{2a} + \frac{4a}{b} - 1\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}\right) + 4\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) - 1\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + 4x - 1
\end{align}

Comment: Should I take the derivative from here? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @TizzleRizzle Yes, just set the derivative to $0$.

Comment: Okay, Just wondering, How did you get the $b/2a$ to equal $(1/2)(1/(a/b))$?

Comment: @TizzleRizzle $b/(2a) = 1/2 \cdot (b/a)$

Comment: so then how do you get the b/a to become 1/(a/b)?

Comment: @TizzleRizzle $1/x$ is the reciprocal of $x$, which flips the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thank you! Finally got it lol

Comment: Wait, hold on a second, I ended up solving through and got
$-1/2x^2 +4 = 0$, then when I solved I got $x^2 = 1/8$
Did I solve this wrong somewhere?

Comment: @TizzleRizzle Substitute $x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{8}}$ for $x$ and see what value you get.

Comment: Ohh yeah youre right Im tripping, sorry lol

Answer (score 1):

The expression can be simplified down to $$(2+\frac{b}{2a})+(\frac{4a}{b}-3)= \frac{b}{2a}+ \frac{4a}{b}-1$$

 By the AM-GM inequality, $$\frac{\frac{b}{2a}+ \frac{4a}{b}}{2}\geq \sqrt{\frac{b}{2a}\cdot  \frac{4a}{b}}=\sqrt2$$

 So the minimum value of the entire expression is $2
\sqrt2-1$. This happens when $\frac{b}{2a}= \frac{4a}{b}$ or $b=2\sqrt2 a, $because a,b are positive.

Comment: By the way @OP, was it on a calculus test? Or was it algebra?

Comment: How do you know that the AM-GM inequality minimises the expression? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3727251/1044958).

Comment: This a question from a practice entrance exam overseas. I can use whatever strategy I want to solve as long as I get the answer corred. 

it was in the calculus section of the test though, if that means anything. Along with one of the other questions I have posted.

Comment: @CarefreeExplorer I mean, what’s the problem? Clearly the minimum value of the sum is $2\sqrt2$, so … I mean, I don’t get why it shouldn’t/couldn’t. Maybe you could elaborate on what your thought process is?

Comment: @insipidintegrator I may be wrong here, but do see the link in my comment.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer I think the minimum is obtained from AM-GM _when_ the GM is independent of the variable. (Yes, seen link and concluded the above)

Comment: @insipidintegrator I'm not fully convinced. I may be misunderstanding something, but can you elaborate on precisely why that is the case.

Comment: If there exists a minimum, say $c$, less than $\sqrt2$, then for some value of a and b the LHS(call it P) of the AM-GM inequality will equal $c$. But this means that $P\lt \sqrt2$ for _some_ value of a and b, but then the AM-GM inequality (which is a proven fact) states that $P\geq\sqrt2$ for _all_ values of a and b. Thus the existence of such c would violate the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I'm onboard with you now!

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer I actually hadn’t really thought about it much. Thanks for making me think!

Comment: This is a very good answer, unfortunately, this would imply that the function attain its minimum at the whole set $\{(t,2\sqrt 2 \, t) : t\in \Bbb R^+\}$ but the OP have an irrefutable mathematical argument to prove that the answer is not that, but $2 \sqrt 2$: "it is a test that was given out to thousands of people across the world. Something like that cannot be "wrong""

Comment: $“x”=2\sqrt2$, so I think they will surely have defined $x=\frac{a}{b}$. P.S. Thank you for the first line :)))))